# A java exception that really does catch all

Tags: java, c++

I'm working with a very errant JNI that throws all sorts of exceptions that I need to catch somehow. (Some of them are as low-level as C++ reference cast exceptions!)

What I want to know is what the accepted (*i.e.* standard) idiom of catching all is in Java; akin to `catch (...)` in C++.

Up to now I've been using

```
} catch (java.lang.Exception e){
    ...
}
```

as I believed that was standard. But I've realised that it is, theoretically possible at least, to derive a class from java.lang.Throwable and throw that, in which case I should really use

```
} catch (java.lang.Throwable e){
    ...
}
```

Only I haven't seen that in source code before so perhaps it's idiosyncratic. Would would you guys do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can catch `Throwable` to catch absolutely everything that can be caught in Java, but note that doing so is rarely a good idea - you can actually interfere with the normal operation of the JVM. The `Error` hierarchy, which is the other part of the hierarchy deriving from `Throwable`, is used for really critical errors such as stack overflow, out of memory, or corrupted .class files. Catching them and not properly throwing them on is a very, very bad idea.

The other problem is that it is insufficient. If you have low-level programming errors in native code, i.e. on the far side of the JNI barrier, your program state may very well be corrupted beyond recovery, and the JVM might not even be able to correctly notice this and throw an exception - it might be corrupted beyond the ability to propagate exceptions.

If the code beyond the JNI bridge is faulty, your only real option is to fix that code. If that isn't an option (e.g. because you don't have access to the source), you have to sandbox the code completely. Write a native process that uses the native code and that you can communicate with somehow (stdin/stdout, networking, whatever), then launch that process from your Java program. If the process dies, it dies, but at least it can't take down your program with it.

Comment: Great answer; and explains why I haven't seen catch java.lang.Throwable in professional code.

Answer (score 0):

Using `catch(Throwable e) {.. }` is the way to go. That is what I did in one of my application where JNI was used.

Answer (score 0):

just catch Throwable, because this will catch everything.

Remember that Java has two fundamental exception types:

- Exception, which is checked
- RuntimeException which is not

Answer (score 0):

you can make your own custom exception and use that exception to throw exception Throwable is parent class of all exceptions

Comment: Making a custom exception will not help here as the exceptions are thrown from JNI

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether you want to catch just `Exception`, or both `Exception` and `Error` (through use of `Throwable`).

As it says in the [`Error` javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html), you probably don't want to catch such things - but then again your situation may seem to warrant it if you know what you're going to do with caught `Error`s.

Answer (score 0):

In my main code I usually always use a `catch Throwable` to make sure that I can get all error conditions and report it appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Throwable is the supper type of Exception.

Exception can catch all checked exceptions